# Different iOS Controls Style on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Why is the navigation bar's default background color white on Xamarin.Forms for iOS and light grey on a Xamarin.iOS application?

Apparently Xamarin.Forms isn't respecting the iOS default styles for controls like ListView and Navigation Bar and I wanted it to be just like vanilla iOS controls.

Comment: Please post some example code. The background color for the navigation bar in an iOS app is the same for Xamarin.Forms as well as for Xamarin.iOS. Your must have made a mistake when comparing you Apps screen.s

Comment: @der_michael I don't believe it was my mistake -- I remember even creating another project without any configuration or code just to see if it showed it as white, and it was. Either way I stopped using it and went back to Xamarin.iOS, which much better.